# Verify signature with openssl and node.js

Tags: node.js, openssl

I'm trying to verify an openssl signature in node.js but can' get it done. I'm using this package: https://github.com/codevibess/openssl-nodejs

What I have: the signature SHA-512 hash, the public key and the token that was signed
What I want: openssl should tell me if the signature is valid

In console I would do:

```
openssl dgst -sha512 -verify pub_key.pem -signature bas64_decoded_hash my_token
```

But when I run:

```
openssl('openssl dgst -sha512 -verify ' + publicKey + ' -signature ' + signature + ' ' + token, function (err, buffer) {
console.log(err.toString(), buffer.toString());});
```

I get errors like "OpenSSL process ends with code 1
No signature to verify: use the -signature option"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up encrypting a token with the private key on the one side and then sending token and encrypted value to the receiver.

On the receiving side I decrypt the value with the public key using:

```
execShellCommand('echo "' + request.body.signature + '" | openssl base64 -d|openssl rsautl -inkey rsa.public -pubin');
```

At the end I check if the decrypted result matches the token.